# How to create multidimensional array depending on DOM element?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a form and I need to create a multidimensional array based on a DOM element that a user can generate more than once with a click of a button.

```
var dimention = $(".stations").length;
```

This is how get the number of `<div class="stations">...</div>"` elements on the page and based on this number I need to create an array.

I currently defined `var stations = [[],[],[],[],[]];` 5 manually but I need to do this dynamically, in case the user wants to create more than 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you could just create an array, and make it the length necessary, then make each section in the array, an array within itself. Something like:

```
var stations = new Array(dimension);
// Create an array of size dimension.
for (var i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
    // At each point in the array, assign a new array object.
    stations[i] = new Array(20);
}
```